# Objective C newbie, one method can change UI elements, others can not

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, user-interface, xcode6

thanks in advance for any input. I have been trying to write a program that interprets a serial command into text change in a label. I can change the label text easily with an Action attached to a button, but for some reason all my attempts at changing the label text outside that button action result in nothing being changed.

```
//  MasterViewController.m

//
//  Created by Daniel Payne on 2/28/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 Daniel Payne. All rights reserved.
//

#import "MasterViewController.h"

@interface MasterViewController ()

@property (strong) IBOutlet NSTextField *score;
@property (nonatomic, strong) ORSSerialPort *serialPort;
@property (nonatomic, strong) MasterViewController *masterView;
@end

static MasterViewController *serialPortHelper = nil;
void connectPort(void) {

    ORSSerialPort *serialPort = [ORSSerialPort serialPortWithPath:@"/dev/tty.usbmodem1411"];
    serialPortHelper = [[MasterViewController alloc] init];
    serialPortHelper.serialPort = serialPort;
    serialPort.delegate = serialPortHelper;
    serialPort.baudRate = @9600;
    NSLog(@"port open");
    [serialPort open];

}
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    connectPort();

    return NSApplicationMain(argc, argv);

}



@implementation MasterViewController
- (IBAction)pushButton:(id)sender {
            [self.score setStringValue:@"1"]; //works
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

}



-(void)awakeFromNib
{

        NSLog(@"View controller instance with view: %@", self.view);



}



- (void)serialPort:(ORSSerialPort *)serialPort didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    if ([string rangeOfString:@"g"].location == NSNotFound) {

        NSLog(@"no goal");
    } else {
        [self.score setStringValue:@"1"]; //does not work
        NSLog(@"GOOOOAL");

    }

}

- (void)serialPortWasRemovedFromSystem:(ORSSerialPort *)serialPort
{
    self.serialPort = nil;
}

- (void)serialPort:(ORSSerialPort *)serialPort didEncounterError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"%s %@ %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, serialPort, error);
}

- (void)serialPortWasOpened:(ORSSerialPort *)serialPort
{
    NSLog(@"Serial port %s was opened", [serialPort.name UTF8String]);

}




@end
```

Comment: To clarify my question, is there anything I am missing that would be required to change the label text from the serialPort or other method?

Comment: Do check whether `serialPort:didReceiveData` is called on the main thread (`[NSThread isMainThread]`). If not, that probably the reason why you are not seeing (some) UI updates.

Comment: what would it look like if serialPort:didRecieveData is called on the main thread? and where would I find it?

Comment: Set a breakpoint in that method and type `expr [NSThread isMainThread]` in the debugger. What result do you get? Alternatively, add `NSLog(@"isMainThread=%d", NSThread.isMainThread);` inside the method and check the console output: again, what result do you get?

Comment: `serialPort:didReceiveData` is definitely running, I see the NSLog of `Goooal` that indicates this. It is being called once `connectPort` initializes and starts to receive data. The specified lines of code, while they are exactly the same, change the label in one method and do nothing in the other.

Comment: [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(SEL) withObject:id waitUntilDone:BOOL] will do it on the main thread

Comment: I will check, just saw your comment.

Comment: this is the output I get from `expr [NSThread isMainThread]`     `(char) $1 = '\x01'`

Comment: So it is (apparently) running on the main thread. Must be a different cause then.

Comment: also from the log `isMainThread=1`  so it is in the main thread.  Also just as a side note thank you both for helping me Alex and Drux

Comment: It is still not changing the UI elements. If anyone else has any ideas let me know

Comment: To make this clear: ORSSerialPort always calls its delegate methods on the main thread/queue. This is [documented behavior](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/ORSSerialPort/1.5.4/Protocols/ORSSerialPortDelegate.html). The problem is undoubtedly (at least partly) what jrturton points out in his answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The instance of MasterViewController that is listening to your serial port is not the same one that you are seeing on screen.

You create a new one and assign it to a static variable - this is not the same one you have loaded from a nib with all its outlets connected.

Log `self` in both methods to confirm.

Comment: To add to this, if you move the code in `connectPort()` into `-viewDidLoad`, I expect that you'll see this start working. That's not to say that's the ideal way to structure this code, but it's a start.

Comment: @AndrewMadsen except you'd use `self` as the helper object, not a new instance, but yes

Comment: Right, should have been more clear about that, thanks.